# How to use solidity assembly to pull out a part of the msg.data?

Tags: solidity

I'm attempting to use a delegatecall as a fallback function like so:

```
function() public payable {
    if (msg.data.length > 0) {
        Log(msg.data);
        require(TRC.delegatecall(msg.data));
    } else {
        revert();
    }
}
```

However, the Log event here shows that my message data is `0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000044e417a98` when all I want are the last 4 bytes for the method signature, `0x4e417a98`. I think I must have to use solidity assembly to pull out these last four bytes but I do not know where to start.